# Does cin anyhow affect new keyword usage in c++?

Tags: c++, object, new-operator

I am trying to get user input using `cin` before creating a pointer and allocating memory using the `new` keyword. The code produces an error.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int a;
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "val of a is " << a;
    int *p = new int;
    p = &a;
    delete p;
 
    return 0;
}
```

The error is:

```
free(invalid pointer)
Aborted(code dumped)
```

Any sort of knowledge on the `new` keyword? How it processes, and its relation with `cin` is welcomed.

Comment: `p = &a;` leaks the value originally assigned to `*p`. `delete p;` followed by `a` going out of scope is a double deletion. Nothing to do with cin.

Comment: Nathan is right. you need to swap `p=&a;` and `delete p;`, remove both the new and the delete or replace `p=&a;` with `*p = a;`

Comment: `a` is an automatic variable. It'll be free'd automatically when it goes out of scope - but you take the address of it (`p=&a`) and `delete` it. If that had worked, it would be deleted twice: one time by your `delete` and one time when it goes out of scope. You also forget (leak) the memory you allocated with `new` when you assign `p` to something else. How should you be able to free the memory you allocated after that? You can't.

Answer (score 3):

Trying to `delete` memory that wasn't allocated with `new` is **undefined behavior**. When `delete p` is called, `p` is pointing at `a`, and `a` was not allocated with `new`. Period. This issue has nothing to do with `cin` at all. The fact that `cin` is being used to assign a value to `a` is *irrelevant*.

Comment: Thanks a lot...Thats a mistake I made..I was working on a larger program..which worked fine..when I didnt have any user inputs before creating object using new..when I tried to get input ..the same error occured..when I tried to get input after the line of creating object..again it worked fine..so tried to bring a small model of the issue..here in the program..this works fine..when p=&a is removed..but in the issue I am working with..I cant figure out why input buffer usage clashes with object craetion

Comment: @KaviyaSubramanian can't really help with that without seeing the actual code you are having trouble with, or a better [mcve] that demonstrates the same issue.